# How do I apply a discount to products in a category?

Tags: magento-1.9

Im trying to set up a rule for my magento products but having some issues, the rules I want o apply are:

If the products are in the category id 3 apply the discount,
If I have 2 items in category 3 and 1 item from a different category apply the discount only to the items in category 3,

If 2 items are the same from category 3 apply the discount.
If 2 items are different but still from the same category apply the discount.
If other items not matching these parameter only apply the discount to the items in the category.

Answer (score 0):

In Shopping Cart Price rules you can add a rule that matches a category, you can also then attempt to add a further condition for quantity but these rules are relatively simple.

I think what you are trying to achieve is too complex for shopping cart price rules and would be better achieved via logic in a module that examines cart content performs the logic on the items present that you want and then adds the discount.

I would look at what modules and code examples are currently available to allow you to implement custom discounts etc, and depending on your level of Magento / PHP development knowledge customise this to achieve what you want.